# Getting a file url for a logged in user and display on screen

Tags: php

Firstly, I am "new"(only been coding for a couple months) to PHP and am trying to get a file for a logged in user to display.

I have tried a few options including `baseband` and `url` but it just dosn't seem to work the way I need it to.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$personCalendar = '/folder\calendars\people';
$personFiles = scandir($personCalendars);

$personID = $_SESSION['Person_ID'];

$test = preg_grep('/'.personID.'/',$personFiles);
print_r($test);

echo basename($test);
```

The output from the `print_r` gives me `Array ( [312] => s15399.ics )` which is great, but I just need the `s15399.ics` part and have it append to the end of the page url something like `https://servername.com/index.php/calendar?s15399.ics` so they can take the file and "subscribe" to their calendar.

`baseband` does not being anything but I am not that surprised by that.

Is this possible, if not, what would be the best way you recommend to do this?

Comment: Baseband? I'm confused, that in context of mobile devices? Do you use that `url()` function? Not sure I'm following. If you just want the value of `$test` element use `reset($test)`. -"Returns the value of the first array element, or FALSE if the array is empty. "

Comment: Sorry, i was testing the `url()` function, but it did not work so I wasn't using it. I have taken it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// using \ in a file path is not going to work. Use / instead.
// $personCalendar = '/folder\calendars\people';
$personCalendar = '/folder/calendars/people';

// scandir will work but it will eventually run into problems 
// if you have lots and lots of files.
$personFiles = scandir($personCalendars);


$personID = $_SESSION['Person_ID'];
function url(){
    return sprintf('%s//%s%s',
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
}
// shouldn't the following be $personID, not personID?
$test = preg_grep('/'.$personID.'/', $personFiles);
print_r($test);
$filename = reset($test);
if ( $filename ) {
    $fullUrl = url() . $filename;
    echo $fullUrl;
} else {
    echo "File not found\n";
}
```

If you need to find a file and you know the file name, you don't need to read all the files. If the file name is the same as the person id, then:

```
$filename = "s{$personID}.ics";
if ( file_exists($filename) ) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! The URL displays nicely. I tried to add the calendar in google with the link and was met with an error `The address that you provided did not contain a calendar in a valid ical or GData format.` so invalid URL? The ics files are stored in a different location to the page file.

Also, what would be a better than `scandir()`? There could potentially be thousands of files to scan through.

Comment: I don't know anything about Google calendar and what file format they accept.  You can't tack on additional questions to an existing question.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. Turns out it isn't being read from outlook or Ical either.

Comment: Is the folder containing the file accessible from the Internet or do you have to pass it through a PHP script?

Comment: It is not accessible from just typing in the url to the file. Also hence the need to provide a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [current();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

```
$link=current($test);
```

Comment: If `preg_grep` returned an array consisting of more than one element which would that return? Asking because I don't like ambiguity in code, but then I have no idea what the pattern for matching on is either :)

Comment: The first element with in the array there are also next() and prev() and last() which will you help you but for now current() do your work

Comment: Confirmed. Wasn't 100% on what it did with the pointer. Why I prefer `reset` in that case. But you are correct.

Comment: for me reset() is a more suitable function in your case but I used current() because It came to my mind first